# Semitransparent Textfield

Tags: java, swing, transparency

How do you make a JTextField semi-transparent? I need about 50% alpha for the background of the text field.

I have tried `textField.setOpaque(false)` then `textField.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,128))`, but it ended up completely transparent. I also tried it without setting opaque to false and the textField became less transparent every time you type.

Comment: It's for a heads up display for a game, so the user will need to be able to somewhat see through it, but they also need to be able to tell where it is (just a border makes it look like just a box). SSCCE coming in a moment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also tried it without setting opaque to false and the textField became less transparent every time you type.

See [Background With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation why this happens and a solution.

Comment: I understand why it happens, but is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Why do you ask questions when you don't bother to read the entire answer and follow the link?

Comment: I saw that page previously, but I don't quite understand the Alpha Container. Do I just construct a new AlphaContainer whenever I add a semitransparent component to the GUI?
And yes, I forgot to read the "and a solution" part of your answer; sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

At some point in the paint chain, you need to take control.

The simplest method would be to override the text field's `paint` method and adjust the graphics composite to provide the transparency you want.

This comes with some additional issues.  The text field MUST be transparent (opaque == false), otherwise you will end up producing repaint artifacts.  You will also need to fill the background of the field manually, as setting the field to transparent stops it painting it's own background...

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTransparentTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTransparentTextField();
    }

    public TestTransparentTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new TransparentTextField("Look ma, no opacity!", 20));
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("/get/your/own/image"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight()- background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TransparentTextField extends JTextField {

        public TransparentTextField(String text) {
            super(text);
            init();
        }

        public TransparentTextField(int columns) {
            super(columns);
            init();
        }

        public TransparentTextField(String text, int columns) {
            super(text, columns);
            init();
        }

        protected void init() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
            super.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1, this approach (overriding paint) makes the background and the text transparent.